# what should i use if i want to update my record if a certain condition its true

Tags: sql-server, if-statement, sql-server-2012

i want to update my records, if the day of the last payment of the client its greater than 100;

```
 update clients set ind_mo = 2,
ind_pay=2
```

if its less than 100;

```
update clients set ind_mo = 1, 
ind_pay = 1
```

if the the own of the client its = 0

```
update clients set ind_mo = 1,
ind_pay = 1
```

i already tried this but it does not update my record if the own its 0

```
if (datediff(day,((select top 1 fec_ven from 
cxc_cuedoc  cue inner join cxc_cliente cli
on cli.cod_cli = cue.cod_cli  where sal_doc !=0 and cue.tip_doc = '010'  and num_doc=cue.num_doc)),getdate())) > 110
update cxc_cliente
 set ind_mora ='2',
IND_JURIDICO = '2';
else
update cxc_cliente
set ind_mora = '1',
ind_juridico ='1'
```

Comment: You're using `SELECT TOP 1`, but you're not ordering your results. This is bad practice. What are the business requirements for determining which record in `cxc_cuedoc` you're supposed to use for the date comparison?

Comment: Which table has the column `fec_ven` ?

Comment: @M.Ali the table cxc_cuedoc

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE Cli
 SET  Cli.ind_mo  = CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(DAY , fec_ven , GETDATE()) > 100 
                         THEN 2 ELSE 1 END
     ,Cli.ind_pay = CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(DAY , fec_ven , GETDATE()) > 100 
                         THEN 2 ELSE 1 END
from cxc_cuedoc  cue 
inner join cxc_cliente cli on cli.cod_cli = cue.cod_cli  
                          and cli.num_doc = cue.num_doc
where sal_doc != 0 
and cue.tip_doc = '010'
```

Or if you are only interested in the last row, maybe something like this...

```
WITH X AS (
SELECT ind_mo , ind_pay , fec_ven 
     , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY cli.cod_cli ORDER BY fec_ven DESC) rn 
FROM cxc_cuedoc  cue 
inner join cxc_cliente cli on cli.cod_cli = cue.cod_cli  
                          and cli.num_doc = cue.num_doc
where sal_doc !=0 
and cue.tip_doc = '010'
)
UPDATE x
  SET  x.ind_mo  = CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(DAY , x.fec_ven , GETDATE()) > 100 
                         THEN 2 ELSE 1 END
     ,x.ind_pay = CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(DAY , x.fec_ven , GETDATE()) > 100 
                         THEN 2 ELSE 1 END 
WHERE x.rn = 1
```

Comment: This will probably work, but if there are multiple records in cxc_cuedoc per each record in cxc_cliente, as suggested by OP's use of `SELECT TOP 1 fec_ven`, then this `UPDATE` may have unintended results.